# booting from live USB when running windows 10 on machine

Tags: windows-10, uefi, usb-boot

**I'm trying to run a Live USB from a Windows 10 system and failing.**

I've made a Linux Mint live USB, so that I could install it and dualboot. I made it by simply formatting a USB stick to FAT32, downloading unetbootin, selecting "Linux Mint" from the dropdown, and pressing create.

I know this specific USB and this method of creating live usbs work, because a couple of days ago I did the same thing with Lubuntu to revive an old laptop, which was, at the time, running Windows XP.

So I make the USB, use Shift+Restart(on the start menu), click run from external device, then USB HDD. The PC restarts and goes straight into Windows 10, completely ignoring my request.

I tried googling for this problem, but all I found was people failing to launch Windows 10 from a USB stick and a single [article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2951559/operating-systems/how-to-install-linux-on-a-pc-with-secure-boot-enabled.html) warning that there might be bootloader signing in the PC, which might cause my problems, but this PC is too old to have that (when I first got it (and I got it used), newest Windows was 7).

What other things can I check for to make the PC actually boot from the USB stick?

Comment: Ensure the USB drive is in the BIOS boot order ahead of the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find why the Windows 10 boot loader would not allow me to run from a live USB, but, as per the comments of @TECHIE007, I decided to simply work around it. The solution was to disable Windows bypassing the BIOS screen, (power options -> change what the power buttons do -> change administrator settings -> disable fast startup) and just go through my own BIOS. From there everything went as expected. Just was interested in why the Windows 10 boot loader wouldn't allow me to boot from a live USB (maybe it was sensing it's impeding death :) ).

Comment: Secure Boot might be enabled.

Comment: Secure Boot was most likely **not** an issue. Chances are this was a bug in Windows and/or in the EFI. Note that, if the computer came with Windows 10 pre-installed, it does *not* have a BIOS, even though the manufacturer may refer to the firmware by that term. The vast majority of modern systems ship with [EFI/UEFI firmware,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) which is radically different from a BIOS. Unfortunately, a lot of bugs still lurk in EFI/UEFI and related software (including OS utilities).

Comment: @fpmurphy1, as I pointed out in my question, (the boot loader signing article), my PC is too old to have Secure Boot, and I couldn't find any options for it in the windows bootloader. Also, I pointed out that the PC is so old, that when I first got it (and I got it used), the newest available windows was windows 7.